# Foreignkey in migrate laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I have a problem when **migrate** in laravel. Ex: I have 2 migrate: *products* and *categories*. The *products* has a **foreignkey** to *categoried* .If I create *products* migration before *categories* migration, when I run `php artisan migrate`, It cann't migrate. But if I create the *categories* first, it works. Can I run it without create again or rename file?

Thanks.

Comment: If you check products table migration, you can see category_id is one of fields. If you don't have already set categories table, it will fail. Plain logic. Check @Flame 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Migrations are run in the order you have defined them (which is by the date in the filename `database/migrations/2022_01_01_000100_create_my_table.php`). If for some reason this order does not work for you because for instance some foreign key requires another table to exist, then you have to change the order of these migrations by changing the filename for instance.

However, it depends on whether you have ran the migrations before on production. If you did, there should be a `migrations` table which contains all the records of the migrations that have been ran. If migrating doesn't work for you on the production server it is often easier to fix it manually and make sure the `migrations` table is up-to-date.

Just remember that you shouldn't be editting migration files themselves for this exact reason, because already-ran migrations will not take your changes into account.